# Why does adding minimum crossing edge always result in spanning tree here?

Tags: graph-theory

In this proof of the cut property, I am trying to understand why we can always replace f with e and still  have a tree spanning all of the nodes in the graph. I understand the fact that if e is not in our 'mst', a crossing edge of greater weight must be in the 'mst'. However, it seems that this crossing edge f could still be relevant in connecting other edges besides just those which e could connect, so that when e is swapped with f, our tree doesn't connect all of the nodes in the graph. I am not seeing the fact that e could accomplish everything f can towards ensuring every node of the graph is connected. How is it that e can always connect all of the nodes which f could connect, resulting in a fully connected mst if e is added into it?
thanks

[image]

Comment: Suppose $G$ is a connected graph on $n$ vertices. What is a necessary and sufficient condition for it to be a tree?

Comment: @Qise this is that there are no cycles. I see that we must remove an edge to remove the cycle. However, It is not clear to me how it is necessarily another crossing edge which we must remove to remove the cycle.

Comment: Can you find a condition on the number of edges maybe?